# Playframework - internationalization inside set tag

Tags: internationalization, playframework

I have a question regarding internationalization in templates.

Usually we use &{'key'} inside a template to replace it with localized message.

I have a template somthing like the following.

```
#{extends 'base.html' /}
#{set pageTitle:'Opps - 404 Error'/}
```

something like

```
"&{'404.message'}"
```

does not work.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you have two options. You can do

```
#{set pageTitle: messages.get('404.message') /}
```

or

```
#{set 'pageTitle'}
   &{'404.message'}
#{/set}
```

I tend to prefer the second approach.

Comment: Thanks, I went with the second way. It is more consistent and readable.

Answer (score 4):

From guillaume.bort:

```
@{Application.index()} is a shortcut for ${actionBridge.Application.index().url}

@@{Application.index()} is a shortcut for ${request.base +
actionBridge.Application.index().url}

&{'hello'} is a shortcut for ${messages.get('hello')}

&{'hello', name} is a shortcut for ${messages.get('hello', name)}

#{get 'title' /} is a shortcut for ${get('title')}
```

So the answer to your question could be `#{set pageTitle: messages.get('error_msg', 404)/}`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the tags were shortcuts. It could come in handy in future :)

Comment: wow.. thats very handy... I wished SO would have a bookmarking feature, so I could bookmark this answer for further reference!